# Crystal Report Display Records Horizontally

Tags: report, crystal-reports-xi

I am new to CR. Can someone help?

I have a record:

ID | Name | Class | re-required

1 | John | MA101 | MA100

1 | John | BIO101 | BIO100

2 | Mary | |

3 | Kay | MA101 | MA100

3 | Kay | BIO101 | BIO100

3 | Kay | CHEM101 | CHEM100

I want the output like this:

ID | Name

1 | John

Additional Information : MA101 MA100 BIO101 BIO100

2 | Mary

Additional Information : NONE

3 | Kay

Additional Information : MA101 MA100 BIO101 BIO100 CHEM101 CHEM100

I created a formula for Additional_Information:

WhilePrintingRecords;
Command.{Class} + " " Command.{Re-required}

and output like this, which is not what I need:

ID | Name

1| John

Additonal Information: MA101 MA100

1 | John

Additonal Information: BIO101 BIO100

Is my formula wrong? Can you help

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with grouping, There should be only one group and it should `ID`.

Now apply your formula to get the result between your formula is correct.